# Display choicefield in admin as input field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a database of maybe 100 users that have each 5-10k products linked to them. In the admin panel loading that page is really slow because of the many products. So what I want to do is replacing it with a regex or at least a number input field that does not preload all the products:

models:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 128)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, )
    testproduct = models.Foreignkey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)

class Product(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

admin:

```
class StoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", ...]
    raw_id_fields  = ["testproduct", ...]
```

This way I get an id input field on the admin page:

[image]

Is there any way I can make it a regex field, so I can search through the `data` attribute of my products as well as the `number` attribute?

Comment: This isn't the complete answer for your case, but you should nevertheless look into Django's [raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) option which allows you to specify foreign keys via a popup instead of a dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, best way to achieve your goal is to add extra field to your model admin form and override save method for it, try this:

```
#admin.py

from django import forms
class StoreAdminModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    regex_field = forms.CharField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        product_regex = self.cleaned_data.get('regex_field', None)
        instance = super(StoreAdminModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)

        # put some more regex validations here
        if len(product_regex) > 0:
            product = Product.objects.filter(data__regex=product_regex).first()
            if product:
                instance.testproduct = product
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Product with data satisfying regex was not found!')

        if commit:
            instance.save()

        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = '__all__'


class StoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = StoreAdminModelForm
    raw_id_fields  = ["testproduct", ]
    fields = ('name ', 'user', 'testproduct', 'regex_field')
    readonly_fields = ('user', )
```

So, the result - you will have special field for regex expression and you will try to get testproduct based on that field (without touching raw_id_field)

Comment: I already am quite satisfied with @Jaap Joris Vens answer, this already reduced the amount of time it needs to load the site by a lot. Do you see any chance of regex implementation here?

Comment: Could you provide more info for what and where do you need to implement regex?

Comment: I re-posted the first post in order to make it more clear. I should have done that before posting a bounty.

Comment: are you sure, that your models are correct? cause the way you wrote it, there will be only one product in a store - cause in your Store model you have Product as foreign key, but i suppose you have a lot of products in the store, right? so you should have Store as foreign key in your Product model, correct me if i misunderstood. I think i know what you need, but i cant help you without correct models and admin forms. Basically you should implement pre_save function for your store model and write needed logic there

Comment: you are right, this is unclear. `testproduct` is just to save ONE product per store, that is used to as a test for a function. I added `store` as a `ForeignKey` to the `Product` model.

Comment: Ok, i will look closer tomorrow. Just to be clear: you are using inlines with your StoreAdmin class for change/add products, and you want to implement custom logic (like regexp) for saving inline products on yours StoreAdmin page, yep?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239675/discussion-between-henry-fool-and-xtlc).

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I have one more question: Is there any way I could make it a "live search" let's say after 3 chars were entered?

Comment: @xtlc i answered you in chat in monday - you can use ajax for such things, it will be even better for your task - so u dont need to create model field for regex, just customize your template + write method to get product by regex expression - using ajax you can call this method after 3 chars were entered -> and put result to the RAW ID field. There are a lot of articles about ajax + django, i think you will easy find some example